# Após usar o .innerHTML para prencher uma DIV, como limpar essa div com outra função?

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Tenho o seguinte código,

```
var resultado;
    var numero;
    var tamanhoNumero;
    var i=0;
    function calcular(){

        numero = document.form.numero.value;
        console.log(numero);
        tamanhoNumero = numero.length;
            console.log("i = " + i);

        for (i = tamanhoNumero; i>=0; i--) {
            console.log("i = " + i);

            console.log("numero.lenght = " + numero.lenght);
            resultado += numero.substring(i, i-1) + '<br>';
        }

        document.getElementById('saida').innerHTML = resultado;
    }
```

Quando eu preencho a 'saida', gostaria de limpar ela antes da próxima operação, isso pode ser feito no começo dessa função mesmo. Como fazer ?

Comment: Não basta colocar `resultado = ''` na primeira linha da função?

Comment: É isso ai, valeu, estava tentando com aspas duplas.

Comment: Só para podermos honrar o SOen, em `numero.lenght` o length está mal escrito

Comment: Aspas simples ou duplas não há diferença. Você possivelmente estava errando em outra coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outras formas similares de **remover o texto de uma tag sem outros elementos filhos** seria:

```
elemento.removeChild(elemento.firstChild);
```

ou

```
elemento.removeChild(elemento.lastChild);
```